# How to share image cache with WebView

Tags: android, webview

I implement a ImageCache module with myself,it can auto download images in html.

but I don't know how to share with WebView's ImageCache, If the image has cached by webview,it will not be downloaded again.

I implements a ContentProvider, If the image has been cached,read from cache,else download from internet. But the images usually appear together and the Webview  display blank for a long time

Answer (score 0):

Try something like `webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/",data, "text/html", "utf8","");`

You might find this website helpful: [Graphing Data](http://rapidandroid.org/wiki/Graphing)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered building your own ContentProvider to access your cache? It's not as scary as it sounds, you only need to extend ContentProvider and hook it into your manifest file.

[Here](http://www.techjini.com/blog/2009/01/10/android-tip-1-contentprovider-accessing-local-file-system-from-webview-showing-image-in-webview-using-content/) is a blog post describing it - I implemented it in an app which makes heavy use of WebViews: [Source on Github](https://github.com/manmal/MockingDroid/blob/master/src/com/manuelmaly/mockingdroid/LocalFileContentProvider.java).

This kind of ContentProvider can load all local files within a WebView - you would have to adapt this idea to either:

- Download all files to sd-card or internal storage before displaying it in the WebView, and simply load the local HTML file via loadUrl(), or
- Only store cached images locally, and replace all occurrences of their original image-locations in the WebView's HTML-code with their cached location (using the above-described extension of ContentProvider). You can manipulate HTML source by "injecting" javascript into the WebView via loadUrl() - with some fine regex or consistent CSS classes within the view this should be doable.

Comment: Thanks, but I have encounter new problems:

Comment: I implements a ContentProvider, If the image has been cached,read from cache,else download from internet. But the Webview sometimes display blank for a long time,and the images usually appear together.

Comment: i would also need the code you use for displaying these images in your webview. the contentprovider code looks fine, nice work.